# pgfplots legend wrong order

Tags: pgfplots

I'm having difficulties with setting the order of the legend entries in the following MWE:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[partial=upright]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage[main=ngerman,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            scale only axis,
            width=0.475\linewidth,
            height=5cm,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=1,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=10,
            legend style={
                at={(0.55,0.95)},
                anchor=north,
                transpose legend,
                legend columns=3,
                legend cell align=left,
                draw=none % Unterdrücke Box
            },
            cycle multiindex* list={
                color list\nextlist
                mark list*\nextlist}
        ]
        \addplot {x};
        \addplot {2*x};
        \addplot {3*x};
        \addplot {4*x};
        \addplot {5*x};
        \addplot {6*x};
        \addplot {7*x};
        \legend{
            \strut $A$,
            \strut $B$,
            \strut $C$,
            \strut $D$,
            \strut $E$,
            \strut $F$,
        }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**What I get is:**

[image]

This is not the order I specified the entries, neither when filling the legend row by row nor when filling column by column.

**What I want would be:**

```
A C E
B D F
```

which is the order I specified the entries, written column by column into the legend.

Comment: Does my answer answer your question? If yes, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) it (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). Otherwise please let us know. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer is fine. Please consider updating it if the issue gets fixed :)

Comment: Thank you for accepting. And of course I'll update it when the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have found a bug here. But if you remove the trailing comma in the `\legend` list everything seems to work fine.

Alternatively you could use `\addlegendentry`s instead of `\legend`.
(`\legend` has higher precedence than `\addlegendentry`, so in the below code this is not a problem.)

(For the record: I filed this in the PGFPlots Tracker as [bug 201](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/201/).)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        scale only axis,
        width=0.475\linewidth,
        height=5cm,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=1,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=10,
        legend columns=2,
        transpose legend,
        legend style={
            at={(0.55,0.95)},
            anchor=north,
            legend cell align=left,
            draw=none % Unterdrücke Box
        },
        cycle multiindex* list={
            color list\nextlist
            mark list*\nextlist
        },
    ]
        \addplot {x};       \addlegendentry{A}
        \addplot {2*x};     \addlegendentry{B}
        \addplot {3*x};     \addlegendentry{C}
        \addplot {4*x};     \addlegendentry{D}
        \addplot {5*x};     \addlegendentry{E}
        \addplot {6*x};     \addlegendentry{F}
        \addplot {7*x};     \addlegendentry{G}

        \legend{
            \strut $A$,
            \strut $B$,
            \strut $C$,
            \strut $D$,
            \strut $E$,
            \strut $F$%     <-- removed the comma
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]